# Can't add custom domains on my deployed django project

Tags: python, django, heroku, webfaction

I recently deployed my Django project on Heroku. The deployment was correct but when I tried to add custom domains, the Heroku denies it by asking me to enter the credit card information for validation. I don't have a credit card and I simply want to connect my GoDaddy domain to my Heroku project. As I've made my other projects in PHP, it was easy and absolutely free to host and add custom domain(Hostinger). So, is there any other platform where I can deploy and add custom domains without any of these fuss ? Or it was my mistake to choose Django as a framework ?

Comment: do you know your heroku ip address?  If so, go to godaddy, and point to it

Comment: I don't know the heroku ip address. Can you please explain more on this.

Comment: If you have an account with heroku, they have given you an ip address.  How do you upload your files? with ssh?  Its that number 192.168.1.1 -- not that, but something with 4 sets of numbers separated by dots

Comment: They didn't provide me any IP address.